# Save and load correctly pandas dataframe in csv while preserving freq of datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I was trying to save a DataFrame and load it. If I print the resulting df, I see they are (almost) identical. The freq attribute of the datetimeindex is not preserved though.

My code looks like this

```
import datetime
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def test_load_pandas_dataframe():
    idx = pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime.now(),
                        end=(datetime.datetime.now()
                             + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)),
                        freq='10min')
    a = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(2*len(idx)).reshape((len(idx), 2)), index=idx, 
                     columns=['first', 2])
    a.to_csv('test_df')
    b = load_pandas_dataframe('test_df')
    os.remove('test_df')
    assert np.all(b == a)


def load_pandas_dataframe(filename):
    '''Correcty loads dataframe but freq is not maintained'''
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0,
                     parse_dates=True)
    return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_load_pandas_dataframe()
```

And I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

It is not a big issue for my program, but it is still annoying.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Which line is reporting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the dataframe you save has columns

`Index(['first', 2], dtype='object')`

but the dataframe you load has columns

`Index(['first', '2'], dtype='object')`.

In other words, the columns of your original dataframe had the integer `2`, but upon saving it with `to_csv` and loading it back with `read_csv`, it is parsed as the string `'2'`.

The easiest fix that passes your assertion is to change line 13 to:

```
columns=['first', '2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

To complemente @jfaccioni answer, `freq` attribute is not preserved, there are two options here

Fast a simple, use pickle which will preserver everything:

```
a.to_pickle('test_df')
b = pd.read_pickle('test_df')
a.equals(b) # True
```

Or you can use the `inferred_freq` attribute from a DatetimeIndex:

```
a.to_csv('test_df')
b.read_csv('test_df')
b.index.freq = b.index.inferred_freq

print(b.index.freq)  #<10 * Minutes>
```